# The app restarts itself after one seconds automatically periodical

Tags: android

I wanted to put my `BoradcastReceiverListerner` - which previously was nested in the `MainActivity` and worked well there - in a separate class since my `MainActivity` has gotten really big. In `onReceive()` I needed to invoke the method `deliverBestAccessPoint()` and `textWifi()` so I decided to do that by using the `Parcelable` interface because the passed data is  `ScanResult` but I am encountering the problem that the app restarts itself after one seconds automatically periodical and wifi scanResult  is not being displayed in the textWifi variable?

BroadcastReceiverListener class:

```
public class BroadcastReceiverListener extends BroadcastReceiver implements Parcelable  {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(
                android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {

            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            final List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            if (results != null) {
                ArrayList<ScanResult> updatedResults = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();
                for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                    String ssid = results.get(i).SSID;
                    if (ssid.startsWith("KD")) {
                        updatedResults.add(results.get(i));
                    }
                }

                Intent updateIntenet = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                updateIntenet.putParcelableArrayListExtra("broadcast_event",
                         updatedResults);
                context.startActivity(updateIntenet);

            }
        }

        else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {

                 }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    }
}
```

onNewIntent method in MainActivity:

```
        @Override
        protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            String intentResult = intent.getStringExtra("broadcast_event");
            if (intentResult != null) {
                List<ScanResult> results = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("broadcast_event");
                String a = deliverBestAccessPoint(results);
                textWifi.setText(a.toString());
            } else {
                textWifi.setText("No route is available.");
            }
        }
```

Manifest:

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <!--    <receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiverListener" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> -->
    </application>
```

Comment: You will never get onnewintent call, as your activity is not singletop,singletask nor singleinstance as per your Manifest file. define launchmode in manifest you will get onnewintent call if you activity is already their else it will start new activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell why your app would be re-starting, but I can see one issue that would prevent `textWifi` from getting populated.

You're calling `intent.getStringExtra("broadcast_event")` when that is actually a `ParcelableArrayListExtra`.

One easy fix would be to just check the return value of `getExtras()`:

```
//String intentResult = intent.getStringExtra("broadcast_event");
            if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
                List<ScanResult> results = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("broadcast_event");
```

As a side note, I don't think it's necessary for your `BroadcastReceiver` to implement `Parcelable`.
The only thing here that needs to implement `Parcelable` is `ScanResult`, [which it does](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html).